# CSS issue only on Safari/iMac

Tags: css, macos, safari

I have a really strange CSS problem (I at least think it is CSS related) with one of my websites, on the clients iMac the 2nd column of the top menu has a unwanted top margin, and I have no idea what causes this. (you can see the problem in this screenshot)

[image]

The websites URL is: http://p538551.webspaceconfig.de/

I have already tested this in all major browsers, including Safari on a MacBook but I can not reconstruct the error, everything looks perfect on all my devices. I also tested it using browserstack - also no problems there.

Does anybody know what might cause this issue, or can at least see the problem as well?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: clients iMac the 2nd column?

Comment: client IMac no columns over there in website?

Comment: @Umair yes on the clients iMac, in the top menu the second column (the word: Maschinen- und Anlagenbau) has a unwanted top margin.

Comment: Can't replicate on my mac either, I know clients can be a pain but if you checked on all devices and browserstack and can't replicate the issue, it could have more to do with your clients setup than any generalised setup.

Comment: @somethinghere well thank you for testing, I am just wondering what settings could be causing this

Comment: I had clients once that decided that installing software updates just wasn't their thing and they were stuck on Safari 10 which gave them a lot of rendering issues. In this day and age, out of date browsers should not be a thing anymore. So maybe check that before digging too deep - they might just be on Safari 8?

Comment: Ok thank you I will ask the client for exact MacOS and Safari version

Comment: the thing is, for me it even works when using Safari on Windows, which is running version 5.1 I believe

Comment: I wouldn't guarantee those are the same Safari's, or that the engine hasn't changed in between. Make sure that your clients is using a reasonably up to date version (11+ at the moment, with the `last 2 versions` directive) before you dig too deep into this rabbit hole. It could be something small, like him having his font-size slightly larger than usual or something. There's a bunch of configuration factors that can cause small issues like this, and it'll be hard to figure out which one it is.

Comment: yes I will have more information once I know the versions, if nothing helps I will try to get a remote connection to inspect what is wrong.